# How to learn chess with ubuntu software?

Tags: games, chess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best chess program for a beginner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43479/whats-the-best-chess-program-for-a-beginner)

I am willing to learn how to play chess and I am an absolute beginner.
I know that Ubuntu has a lot of chess programs. So, after reading about tactical stuff on the internet, I installed a program called "Brutal Chess" and started playing. I was allways beaten by the computer, so I decided to try other programs.

I finally found DreamChess, for which the AI is not so though. Though, I also discovered eboard and crafty, which seem to allow me to analyse games and to study from these analysis. I just don't know how to do this. Does anyone know how to do that?