# What's the best chess program for a beginner?

Tags: software-recommendation, games, chess

Pychess wouldn't work for me and after trying other software I settled for Eboard. I can play a basic game with it but the interface is intimidating and there appears to be no documentation. Is there a tutorial somewhere or should I try some different software?

Comment: Rinzwind makes a good point.  There are several good books on the subject though.  http://www.amazon.com/Chess-5334-Problems-Combinations-Games/dp/1579125549/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1305376719&sr=1-1  http://www.amazon.com/Chess-Tactics-Champions-step---step/dp/081293671X/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1305376719&sr=1-3  and http://www.amazon.com/Chess-Advantage-Black-White-Grandmasters/dp/0812935713

Comment: It has to do with ubuntu. I am wondering how can I use the software that ships with ubuntu as a computer-aided learning tool.

Comment: additionally. It would be nice if someone would tag this with the chess tag.

Comment: done @pedrorolo

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173999/what-fics-chess-clients-are-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### glchess

To install glchess in Ubuntu 14.04-16.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install glchess
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. I haven't tried out a network game, but it detects the computer engines no problem.

Comment: Can you provide some reasons to use glchess?

Answer (score 4):

I played with PyChess (It's in the Software Center) for a while. Among other things, it can give hints for what the best move would be for your current situation. You can also choose the difficulty, so you can start at a low level, and after you've beaten your computer a couple of times move up to a stronger opponent.

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried this program and it is really cool, though, it's AI is really tough. Which engine and which setting (from 1 to 8) do you recommend to an absolute begginer? I've never been able to beat "crafty" or "pychess" until now.

Comment: To be honoust I don't know what exact settings I used. I've played around a little on a rainy afternoon, but never used it much.

Comment: In your case I would start on level 1 and see if you can beat the computer. And also try to use hint/spy mode and undo. It will help analyzing your moves and improving game. Just keep on practicing and learn from your mistakes :)   (sorry for double post, I couldn't edit my previous one)

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [gnome-chess](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-chess) [image: Install gnome-chess]

A screenshot:

[image: A Chessboard]

Comment: Can you provide some reasons to use gnome-chess?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Chessmaster even though it isn't free and only has a bronze raiting on [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4502), because of the tutorials/lessons by Josh Waitzkin that are really awesome, especially for beginners.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm cheating here... But I would recommend [Sparkchess](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/khgabmflimjjbclkmljlpmgaleanedem?hl=en-US) or sparkchess.com. The free version is web-based, and doesn't have too many features, but it's a nice interface, and the easiest AI is pretty easy (heck, even I can beat it pretty easily).

Answer (score 0):

If you like to play in temrinal, you might like http://nocheto.sallyx.org/

Its not free, but not expensive and it is great for studying chess.

Answer (score 0):

Scid vs. PC.
Its free and it's a great toolkit for all your chess needs.  You can find it in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Xboard.
Its free and again you can find it in the Ubuntu Software Center.

If you use the Synaptic Software Manager you can find a great command line tool called pgn-extract.